# MySQL WorkBench Enchanced Entity Relationships with Rails Relationships

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, associations, entity-relationship

I've been tasked with creating a database diagram of a current rails web application in development. I have several relationships already created in the rails application.

```
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :users
```

I used MySQL Workbench EER Diagram tool. When I pull in the Company table and the User table, MySQL does not understand that there is a relationship between the two tables.

1. I'm wondering if there is a performance impact with MySQL not having the relationship created.
2. Is there a way when generating my migrations in rails, to create this relationship in MySQL?

Comment: Have you looked at the gem Rails-ERD (http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/)?  That can help.

Comment: Did not know about that. It does accomplish the issue that I have. Any thoughts on the points 1 & 2?

Comment: Re 1, its primarily the indices that drive performance and those can be specified in Rails migrations.  Rails is creating the foreign keys in its migrations just as you would directly (look at the generated SQL), so I doubt you're seeing a cost from using Rails in this way as long as you have indices specified.

Comment: Re 2, the "ruby way" is to move the logic all into the model and don't do anything per se in MySQL.  No null restrictions or the like, rather have Ruby specify.  There are good and logical reasons for doing this (for instance, not having behavior specified across layers, but rather encapsulated in the model) but it does take some getting used to if you're experienced in older languages or a DBA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your current task of creating a database diagram you can use the Rails gem suggested by rdnewman. Just follow the steps on the link below:

http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/install.html

Answering your two other questions:

1. There's no problem in MySQL. The thing is that MySQL Workbench needs foreign keys to create the relationships between your tables. You could do that by yourself, for instance, setting your `user_id` attribute from the Post model as a foreign key from the `posts` table. What Rails ERD does is that it loads your Active Record models and processes all their attributes and associations (has_one, has_many, belongs_to, etc.), combining it into a single diagram.
2. In order to have this relationship shown in MySQL, you'll need to create foreign_keys on your models. However, the Rails default behaviour is that the column used to hold the foreign key on a model is the name of the association with the suffix _id added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly.

You can find more info on this [Association Basics Guide for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key).